# How to change the formatting of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string field with names formatted as follows:

`John Doe(CEO) - Company Name,`

Note: for whatever reason there’s no space between the last name and the parentheses, and a comma at the end.

I want to format it like this:

`John Doe, CEO`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use SQL [replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function if the format is same for all existing names , something like below -

```
Select replace(replace('John Doe(CEO)','(',', '),')','')
```

**Update:**
If you want to format data of one column, then you can replace 'John Doe(CEO)' with column name, something like -

```
Select replace(replace(MyColumn,'(',', '),')','') From MyTable
```

Comment: How would I go about applying that function to all variations of names in the field? All of the values in the field are in that same format. Thanks.

Comment: @DPool34 . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you asked.  And this seems to answer that question.  If you have *another* question, than ask another question with appropriate data and desired results and explanation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff apologies. I thought the string in the function, ‘John Doe(CEO)’ was only going to apply to that specific example value and not all values.

Comment: @DPool34 . . . Oh, you would replace that with the column name.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah, I realized that after posting the reply. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I tried it out and I'm getting a "replace function requires 3 arguments" error. I used the following:    **Select replace(replace(table.ColumnName,'(',', '),')','')**

Comment: @DPool34 - can you post the complete query, I don't see any problem with `Select replace(replace(table.ColumnName,'(',', '),')','')`